# getPopupReminders() ignores default reminders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I wrote a script to query Google Calendar events, to see if they have reminders set - but it doesn't seem to detect default reminders.

```
var arEvents = myCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

for (var i = 0; i < arEvents.length; i++) {

    var popups = arEvents[i].getPopupReminders();
    var sms = arEvents[i].getSmsReminders();
    var eml = arEvents[i].getEmailReminders();

    Logger.log(popups.length);
    Logger.log(sms.length);
    Logger.log(eml.length);
}
```

`popups.length` is `0` - no reminders. Same with `sms.length` and `eml.length`. OK, so I go look in Google Calendar, and that's not correct: each event has a reminder set. But it's the *default* reminder. Maybe that doesn't count?

So I delete the default reminder and manually create a new popup reminder.
Now `popups.length` is `1`.

Uh... how do I detect ALL reminders, including default ones?

Comment: You mention `popups`.. but what about the others?

Comment: Updated the post to answer (same result)

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use the REST API to access default reminders: https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#default_reminders

Comment: Thanks, @tehhowch. Any idea if that's possible from within apps script?

Comment: Yes, it is an advanced service.